# Converting units (cm to in) for some observations in R

Tags: r

I have a data set where some observations are in cm and some are in inches. I need to convert all of the values to inches. The number is in one column and the unit is in another.

```
height   unit
12.0       in
15.0       in
45.0       cm
13.0       in
52.0       cm
61.0       cm
```

and basically I just want all of them in inches. Should I use some kind of if statement, or subset the data where the unit is cm? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R base 1:

```
> dat$height[dat$unit=="cm"] <- dat$height[dat$unit=="cm"]*0.393701
> dat$unit <- "in"
> dat
    height unit
1 12.00000   in
2 15.00000   in
3 17.71654   in
4 13.00000   in
5 20.47245   in
6 24.01576   in
```

R Base 2:

```
dat$height <- with(dat, ifelse(unit == "cm", height * 0.393701, height))
```

More readable with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% 
    mutate(height = if_else(unit == "cm", height * 0.393701, height))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dt <- data.table(
  height = c(12.0, 15.0, 45.0, 13.0, 52.0, 61.0),
  unit = c("in", "in", "cm", "in", "cm", "cm")
)

dt[, height_in_inches := ifelse(unit == "cm", height / 2.54, height)]

dt
#    height unit height_in_inches
# 1:     12   in           12.000
# 2:     15   in           15.000
# 3:     45   cm           17.717
# 4:     13   in           13.000
# 5:     52   cm           20.472
# 6:     61   cm           24.016
```